# Microsoft Azure,Webjob, in which timezone a webjob runs if I schedule a webjob to run daily at specified time using cron expression

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I scheduled a webjob to run daily at 2 am using cron expression (0 0 2 * * *) following tutorial from [Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)
 and my server is created in "north central US" region, so i hope it should run in US central timezone but seems it running at different time than what i specified.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the comments mentioned [`here`](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/), WebJobs run into the timezone configured for the WebApp where your WebJob is hosted. From this post:

[image]

Assuming you have not configured anything for the timezone, your cron job should use UTC which is the default timezone in Azure.

From [`Changing the server time zone on Azure Web Apps`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/04/06/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps/), you can specify the time zone you want your application to run in by making an application setting called `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` and set it to a proper value. From this blog post:

> If your app is hosted as a Web App on the Azure App Service (formerly
>   known as Azure Websites), until recently you were completely out of
>   luck. However there is now an easy and supported way to change the
>   time zone for your w3wp process (and any processes it spawns):
>
> **All you need to do is add an Application Setting (via the portal or
>   the management APIs) called WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and set that to the name
>   of the time zone as defined in the Windows Registry under
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ (for
>   example, “AUS Eastern Standard Time”)**.

Comment: I see it's running in UTC(GMT) timezone.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the reg key. I added that to the [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#set-the-time-zone).

Comment: Thanks. Microsoft needs to stop hiding important documentation information into blog posts... (I was looking the answer to "Which TimeZone do WebJobs run on", I'm already using WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and I wanted to make sure it would apply there too)

Comment: Use with caution if you set it to a timezone with daylight saving time. If you use a daily pattern the run after the offset change will start on the wrong time.

Comment: How can I configure it so the DST is auto?

Comment: Valid values here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)

Comment: I set my timezone to `GMT Standard Time`.  The jobs are now running on UK time, which is technically incorrect as we are on BST (daylight savings).  It's the result I wanted, but confusing!

Answer (score -1):

The default time zone is GMT as per the MS documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-time-zones

Comment: It is not GMT, it is UTC.