# Azure Web Job running for two timezones, twice

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have given my Web Schedule for the azure web job as 000***. I uploaded this from PST Timezone. The web job runs at 12:00 AM UTC and again at 12:00 AM PST.
Why is it picking two time zones to run the job and how to ensure it only picks one timezone? Could some one please help.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where you have this cron expression? There are multiple workflows that use them.

Comment: I created this job in visual studio and supplied the cron expression in settings.job file

Comment: Just to be sure, you have spaces in your CRON expression right? As in: **0 0 0 \* \* \***

Comment: Here is a related [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856122/microsoft-azure-webjob-in-which-timezone-a-webjob-runs-if-i-schedule-a-webjob-t) which has stated the timezone a webjob runs using cron expression, you could refer to it.

Comment: Nothing I can think of would explain the double firing. Are you sure that you don't have another source firing it, like Azure scheduler?

Comment: Facing same problem. Did you found the cause / solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE application setting to a timezone string, e.g. Pacific Standard Time, on your app service/web app. And see if it runs properly or not.